# Create a new infix operator

Tags: programming, core-language

It is well known that the infix operator `@@` is used as a short form of `Apply`.

For example, both `Apply[f,{a,b,c}]` and `f@@{a,b,c}` return `f[a,b,c]}`

Also the infix operator `@@@` is used as a short form of `Apply` when it is used for levelspec `{1}`

For example, both `Apply[f,{{a,b},{c,d}},{1}]` and `f@@@{{a,b},{c,d}}` return `{f[a,b],f[c,d]}`

I would like to create a new infix operator named `@@@@` (or other) to express `Apply[f,expr,{2}]`  in a short form like `f @@@@ expr`.

Is it possible to create a new infix operator equivalent to some more verbose command ?
Also which are the valid names I could use ?