# Is there any way to define a new binary operator?

Tags: operators

I am looking to define a new operator that would work similarly to the + or - operator.  My end goal is to make a dice operator for calculating random distributions in the normal d20 fashion (e.g. 5d6 meaning 5 six sided die).  I have been trying to find how to overwrite an operator or create a new one in the documentation, but I am not really finding much.  I know how to do it in C++, but that hardly translates.

As an extension I would like to include the ability to calculate with some dice a friend of mine has that are bimodal or trimodal.

Comment: Any particular reason to go through such machinations as opposed to using *Mathematica*'s probability functions?

Comment: @rasher practice creating my own operators.  It is very much so a learning exercise for when I go to do more complicated projects.  Also, I am using Mathematica to work out some math for a new d20 system that I am building with a friend and being able to use the same dice rolling system as is in the tabletop game would be very beneficial for making sure balance is maintained and such.

Comment: In that case, read the documentation re: *upvalues*, *Notation Package*, and *Operators without built-in meanings* to get an idea how to do such a thing "safely". You can also modify the behavior of the actual *Mathematica* operators, generally not a good idea. Search this site for keywords *Operator*, *Overload*, *Infix* and you'll get some hits with good information. Otherwise, a much too broad question without specific, well-defined examples of what you're trying to accomplish if it's beyond playing with capabilities of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Specific examples are easy enough, and I can tell that you have never played a d20 game or they would be readily apparent. specifically I want to make a binary operator that will work like this (d for now): 2d6 meaning that 2 dice with 6 sides are rolled, or 3d8 meaning 3 8 sided dice are rolled.  by extension, 2d6+7 would roll 2 six sided die, then add 7 to the final value, and then 4*(2d6+7)+4d6+2d8 would complete the 2d6+7 opperation 4 times, then add the value of a 4d6 and 2d8 operation.  This is a nearly exact example from my current character.

Comment: @Adam You cannot create a new binary operator in Mathematica, but there are existing operators with no built-in meaning.  You can attach a definition to these.  Check here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorsWithoutBuiltInMeanings.html  Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think the closest you could get would be something like `x_ \[CirclePlus] y_ := Total[Table[RandomInteger[{1, y}], {x}]]`

Comment: My inner D&D geek encouraged me to vote to reopen this question, but it appears to be a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39696/7167)

Comment: Related: [(6338)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6338/121), [(6355)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6355/121), [(39696)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39696/121).  Also see: [(30425)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/121)